# Auto posting in instagram from website using PHP

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

Is it possible to auto post images on Instagram from a website using PHP?
Like Facebook post and Twitter post.

Comment: yes using api https://instagram.com/developer/

Comment: Use API for php given by instagram.

Comment: @MrCOOL are you sure about that ?

Answer (score 4):

## You cannot post pictures to Instagram via the API.

---

An alternative is to use [this](https://github.com/mislav/instagram/). It's the Instagram API, however it's been reversed engineered and explains how to use it (including uploading media).

Not sure how well this works.

Comment: is it possible using core php?

Comment: I'm not not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to post images on Instagram using the API.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to share images/post on [Instagram](http://www.instagram.com/MentoringMind) while its possible only using Instagram Mobile App.